# Is there a way to get the values for the explanatory variables from a prediction using sklearn for multiple linear regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

I'm trying to understand if there is a way, using the `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()` to get the values for the explanatory variables, given a prediction of `X`.

For example - looking at MPG of a car. I can build the model using multiple explanatory variables and then predict (successfully) the MPG for a given set of X. However, can I do the reverse and give `Y` and then get the predict `X` values?

Sorry if not very clear!

Comment: This is not one-to-one! Each value in `y` can have different possible combinations of `X`, f.i. `y = b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2` with `b0 = 5, b1 = 2, b3 = .5` yields for a specific set of x `x1 = 3.5, x2 = 7` --> `y = 15.5 = 5 + 2 * 3.5 + 0.5 * 7.` but also `x1 = 0, x2 = 21` --> `y = 15.5 = 5 + 2 * 0 + .5 * 21`. So: **No, it is NOT possible to get the X-values from the predicted y-value** (except for some very basic and specific cases)!

Answer (score 0):

When approximating some values `Y` associated to some points `X` using linear regression what we are looking is for the nearest linear function (f(x) = ax + k) to the points in a least square sense. So you are not getting `Y` but you are rather getting the linear function that best approximates your input.

Can you do the opposite that is build a function that predicts $X$ rather than $Y$. Consider the example in [sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#examples-using-sklearn-linear-model-linearregression) we are going to tune it a bit.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
>>> X = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]])
>>> # y = 1 * x_0 + 2 * x_1 + 3
>>> y = np.dot(X, np.array([1, 2])) + 3
>>> # Changing y <-> X 
>>> reg = LinearRegression().fit(y, X)
>>> # Changing y <-> X 
>>> reg.score(y, X)
0.8269230769230769
>>> reg.coef_
array([[0.23076923],
       [0.38461538]])
>>> reg.intercept_
array([-0.46153846, -1.26923077])
>>> reg.predict(np.array([[16.]]))
array([[3.23076923, 4.88461538]])
```

This could let you predict your explanatory variables from the MPG of your vehicles. Although this works take into account that this approach will probably give you very bad results as you are trying to approach a cloud of points inside a multidimensional space with a line inside that space. Take a look at your score before trying to predict anything with your model.